# Should I 301 or just let google recrawl?

Tags: seo

I recently changed my site (same domain, just went from static to wordpress), every link is now different.  Should I try to get a list of links (webmaster tools) and set up 301s for each one or just let google come and do it's thing next time around.  I have a complete sitemap for the new site.

Comment: Do you care about SEO?  If you do then 301.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it from an user perspective, there's more to URLs than what happens to appear in search results.

Users have bookmarks, other sites have links, and so on. If someone has gone to the effort of bookmarking or linking to content you've produced, it's a bit strange to upset them and break their links, when you have the tools at your disposal to provide a transition.

Of course, you could limit your efforts to persisting permalinks if your previous site had such a concept and focus on getting those working as intended if the workload to map everything is too large.

Comment: So, where can i get a list of links google has? just site:mysite.com?  I thought you could get a list from webmaster tools, but I dont see it.